# Converting from string to hex and subtracting

Tags: ruby, string, hex

I am trying to extract two hex strings from a file, convert them to integers, and subtract:

```
reg_one = line.strip
reg_one_addr = reg_one[reg_one.index('0x')+2...-1].hex  
puts reg_one_addr  

reg_two = line.strip  
reg_two_addr = reg_two[reg_two.index('0x')+2...-1].hex  
puts reg_two_addr  

diff = reg_two_addr - reg_one_addr
```

I am getting an error when I do this:

```
`-': nil can't be coerced info Fixnum (TypeError)
```

I have tried to go from `hex` to `to_i(16)`, and they both do the same thing. I print out the values after I convert them, and they come out correct. I'm lost.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reg_one_addr, reg_two_addr =
[reg_one, reg_two].map{|s| s.sub(/.*(?=0x)/, "").hex}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[reg_one, reg_two].map{|s| eval(s).to_i}.reduce(:-)
```